# How can I copy external files in /etc/myproject using autoconf?

Tags: xml, autoconf, automake

I'm working on a library that checks the validity of xml files. Of couse, I need to use some xsd files to validate schema and so on.

Now, I'm done with this library, and I'm on preparing it's deployment. I chose autoconf to do so, and I'm stuck on the way I have to copy my xsd files into my project destination.

Here's my configure.ac file :

```
AC_PREREQ(2.59)
AC_INIT(bonjour, 0.1, ymettier@libertysurf.fr)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_MAKE_SET
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(xmlSchemaParse, xml2, [], [
    AC_MSG_ERROR([libxml2 is missing])
])

AC_SEARCH_LIBS(cos, m, [], [
    AC_MSG_ERROR([libm is missing])
])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(xmlC14NDocDumpMemory, crypto, [], [
    AC_MSG_ERROR([libcrypto is missing])
])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(SHA1_Init, ssl, [], [
    AC_MSG_ERROR([libssl is missing])
])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
        Makefile
        src/Makefile
        ])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Thanks

Comment: I hope you're not planning to force users to install 3rd party package data in `/etc` - something like `${prefix}/share` or would make more sense.